# Go debugging with GDB using Visual Studio Code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to set up lauch.json file, so that we can debug Go file with GDB using VSC?

Answer (score 0):

lauch.json won't be enough to achieve that. To actually use GDB from VS Code you will need a plugin supporting GDB. You can probably try "Native Debug" plugin for that. But I'd like to point out that GDB has several issues with debugging Go programs. And generally recommended debugger for Go is delve. And debugging with delve is supported (among many other things) by "Go for Visual Studio Code" plugin. Both plugins include detailed instructions on necessary configuration.

Comment: Thank for your help ^^